# Basic question on C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, arm

Consider this overly simple test:

```
class foo
{
    public:
        foo(int i);
        template< typename T > foo(T);
};

template<> foo::foo(int i) {}
```

Now, GCC is happy to accept this when compiling, but the RVCT compiler issues an error:

```
test.cpp", line 11: Error:  #792: "foo::foo(int)" is not an entity that can be explicitly specialized
 template<> foo::foo(int i) {}
```

Barring the issue of "why would you want to do this", is this legal C++ (from an academic point of view?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to let you know - compiles + runs fine on VS2010

Comment: It works for me.  With both g++ and VC++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to do an explicit specialization of `template<typename T> foo(T)` where T=int.

Did you actually want this?

```
template<typename T> foo::foo(T) {
}
```

--- EDIT ---

Just to make it clear: "explicit specialization" is legal in C++, but apparently your compiler does not support it (on individual methods anyway, maybe it does on whole classes?).

Comment: Don't think that was the question.

Comment: He is getting an explicit specialization error on compiler that apparently does not support explicit specialization. I think I answered both "is this legal" and "why do I get this error".

Comment: Where are you saying it's legal C++?

Comment: I didn't think I needed to specify that "explicit specialization" is legal.

Comment: Maybe not; but that was the question ;)

Comment: FYI, using this works with RVCT (but not with GCC):
template<> foo::foo<int>(int i) {}

Comment: Damn, I realized that I declared the default foo constructor incorrectly. I meant ti use foo(int i) and not foo(char i). Original question has now been updated